# Passing Data from ajax in js file to php file and print php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to send data from a php page to another php page through JavaScript with ajax and the getting the new page to open with the data that was sent so that the user can print the page.. here is the js snippet processDateP and sourceID2 are entered by user.

```
$("#PrintShelf").click(function() {

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "print2.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: ({processDate: $('#processDateP').val(), sourceID: $('#sourceID2').val()}),
            success: function(data){
                if('#sourceID2' != null ){
                    window.open('print2.php');
                }
            }
        });

});
```

I want this to open the file PHP file print2.php, but it either opens the file with no data if i move window.open outside of success function or it sends the data and the page popluates correctly (can see using firebug) but does not open the window..I have run just the print2.php file alone with dummy values and it works and prints.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @RiggsFolly Putting parentheses around an expression isn't a problem.

Comment: When you do `window.optn('print2.php')`, you're calling the script with no parameters. It needs to save the data from the AJAX call in a session variable, and then use that when it gets called with no parameters.

Comment: @Barmar OK, something new learnt today

Comment: i figured that was it--any ideas on how to do that

Comment: session_start();   
$sourceID = $_POST['sourceID'];
$ProcessDate= $_POST['processDate'];  
is what i have in print2.php